# Unix file mv error

Tags: unix

I am trying to read from a file in unix that contains filenames and move the files from one directory to another. But it's giving me an error:

> "mv: cannot stat `REGPC_20170224113009_1111_S.dat': No such file or
>   directory"

Can someone please help?

Tried below script:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 while read file; 

 do 
     mv "$file" /opt/mounts/tes/summit/archive/
     done < /opt/mounts/tes/summit/inbound/rpm_file_list.txt
```

Comment: Is your current working directory the directory that contains REGPC_20170224113009_1111_S.dat?

Answer (score 0):

As statedm **cannot stat `REGPC_20170224113009_1111_S.dat** ; where you are trying to run the script the file, REGPC_20170224113009_1111_S.dat does not exist. Check manually if the path is correct.